# ContainerView in NavigationController breaks segue animation

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Well I needed a fixed header over my collection view so I added a view controller with a container view embedding my page view controller which loads a bunch of collection views. This works fine, I still have to set the content insets but it works.

My problem is that this somehow makes the segue animation of the background jump, instead of fade. Did someone encounter a similar problem and know how to solve this?

Because videos say more then images:

[image: Demo]

And images more than text, my Storyboard:

[image]

Thank you very much, greetings :)